# VIM: function name autocomplete with parameters

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am new to VIM, and I just figured out <kbd>CTRL + N</kbd> could auto complete the function name for me.

However, how can I get it to show parameters as well? I am using **Cscope** and **ctags**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? `<C-]>` usually jumps to the definition of the tag under your cursor. The shortcut for completing a function name in *insert* mode using `tags` is `<C-x><C-]>`.

For some languages, like PHP, the omnicompletion function opens a small preview window with the signature of the function you just completed. Most omnicompletion functions don't use this trick, though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the C programming language. If so then check out [Clang Complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302). Another option would be [Eclim for C/C++](http://eclim.org/vim/c/project.html), which is currently alpha and might not be what you want anyway. Yet another option would be using Eclipse with [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/).